# Procedure to add a new Filter in alfresco?

Tags: java, filter, alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to create a new SSO filter in to my existing alfresco bundle. 
Steps which I tried are;

1. Creating a simple Java project in Eclipse and creating a class which implements Filter and writing code there.
2. Then extract the project as a JAR file and putting it into share/WEB-INF/lib.
3. Registering that filter in share/WEB-INF/web.xml.

Is it the right way of adding a new filter?
If not, please share the right procedure...

Comment: Does it work? Do you hit any problems with doing that?

Comment: Not working.., the filter is not executing I think. Don't know the actual procedure to create a filter. So before checking my code, let me know, am I following right steps or not...

Comment: I would suggest you create a "Hello World" webapp, and then follow some basic filter tutorials to add a test filter into that. Only when you grasp those basics is it worth trying with something more complex like Alfresco...

Comment: I have tried that. Done samples in web app. Now, I am in need of adding one filter in Alfresco, So please let me know the procedure of adding a filter in Alfresco.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is the right procedure. But your filter must respect some rules to work well, btw in web.xml the definition order of your filters is important.